# Warning: Undefined variable $yes_checked in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\update\\wp-content\\plugins\\zeinab-plugin\\setting.php on line 47

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

> Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\update\wp-content\plugins\zeinab-plugin\setting.php
> on line 40
>
> Warning: Undefined variable $yes_checked in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\update\wp-content\plugins\zeinab-plugin\setting.php
> on line 47

We have this error and this is my code:

```
<?php
//"manage_option" سطح دسترسی 
function picf_setting_menu(){
    add_menu_page('PCIF plugin setting','PCIF','manage_options' ,'picf-options', 'picf_plugin_option_page' );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'picf_setting_menu');
function picf_plugin_option_page(){
    ?>
<div class="wrap">
    <form action="options_php">
        </fieldset>
        <?php
        settings_fields("picf_plugin_options");
        do_settings_sections("picf_plugin");
        submit_button('save change','primary');
        ?>

    </form>
</div>
<?php
}
function picf_plugin_admin_init(){
   $args=array(
      'type'=>'string',
      'sanitize'=>'picf_plugin_validate_option',
      'default'=>Null
   );
   register_setting("picf_plugin_options", "picf_plugin_options",$args);
   add_settings_section("picf_plugin_main","تنظیمات پلاگبن","picf_plugin_main_section","picf_plugin");
   add_settings_field("picf_plugin_name_force","فیلد نام اجباری باشد؟","picf_plugin_setting_name_force","picf_plugin","picf_plugin_main");
   //add_settings_field("picf_plugin_name_force","فیلد ایمیل اجباری باشد؟","picf_plugin_setting_name_emeil","picf_plugin","picf_plugin_main");

}
add_action('admin_init','picf_plugin_admin_init');
    function picf_plugin_main_section(){
        echo  "تنظیمات فرم";
    }
    function picf_plugin_setting_name_force(){
        $option=get_option('picf_plugin_options');
        $name_force= $option['name_force'];
        if($name_force=="yes"){
            $yes_checked="checked";
        }else{
           $no_checked="checked";
        }
       echo "<fieldset>";
       echo "<input type='radio' name='picf_plugin_options[name_force]' value='yes' $yes_checked > بله &nbsp  " ;
       echo "<input type='radio' name='picf_plugin_options[name_force]' value='no' $no_checked>   &nbspخیر";
       echo "</fieldset>";
    }
```

Comment: `$yes_checked` could be undefined if `$name_force` doesn't equal "yes". You should never write code which uses a variable in a scenario where there is a chance it might not exist.

Comment: And the first error about array offset is probably because `$option` is null. Have you done any debugging to find out why?

Comment: I saw this code in a tutorial video and there was no problem in the video

Comment: @ADyson, I concur; in this case, we should also include a `$yes_checked` value in else. It can be null, but it must be present.

Comment: @zynbmoallemi, Could you please share the extended source? How do you set the `get_option('picf_plugin_options');`?

Comment: `there was no problem in the video`...that's largely irrelevant. _You_ have a problem in _your_ environment and so you need to debug and find what's different in your setup compared to the video. It seems that in your case, `get_option('picf_plugin_options');` does not return a value. Maybe no such option exists in your environment, or maybe there's a bug in that function. we can't really know, from sitting here.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about the `$option` variable, it seems `get_option()` actually doesn't bring anything with it.

However, for the second one, you may use the following code:

```php
if($name_force=="yes"){
    $yes_checked="checked";
    $no_checked="";
} else {
    $yes_checked="";
    $no_checked="checked";
}
```

> I know it's not a legit way but it works!

At least for now, it can help you.

I hope it's helpful!